# Pairing two elements for accessibility purposes with .accessibilityLabeledPair(role:id:in:) in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

In the [Accessibility in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/238/?time=1172) session from WWDC19, the presenter said (20min): "In an upcoming seed of SwiftUI you'll be able to (...) set up a connection between the label on the left and the popup button on the right."

Checking at the available APIs, I assume this is done with the [.accessibilityLabeledPair(role:id:in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accessibilitylabeledpair(role:id:in:)) modifier. I haven't been able to make it work. In my mind, this would work similarly to [labelFor in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#labelFor)? Has anyone used this modifier successfully?

Using some code like the one below, where I first give a text view the label role and a button the content one. And then both the same Id and namespace. I would expect VoiceOver to focus on both elements as one and for the accessibility label to be the text in the text view. Instead, for me, this behaves exactly the same as if I don't apply the modifier. VoiceOver focuses on the text first and, after a swipe to the right, it focuses on the button. Am I misunderstanding how this should work?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State private var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("I agree on the terms and conditions")
                .accessibilityLabeledPair(role: .label, id: "aPair", in: namespace)
            Button {
                isOn = !isOn
            } label: {
                isOn ? Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill") : Image(systemName: "circle")
            }
            .accessibilityLabeledPair(role: .content, id: "aPair", in: namespace)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Believe you need to use the `.accessibilityRepresentation` modifier on the HStack, right now your second `accessibilityLabeledPair` should be on the button rather than on the Hstack.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer! Yeah, I think using `.accessibilityRepresentation` can be an option. I actually wrote about this in an article, [Accessibility in SwiftUI explained for UIKit developers](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/accessibility-uikit-developers/), some time ago.

But I think using named controls as it is explained in [SwiftUI Accessibility: Named Controls](https://medium.com/@r.whitaker/swiftui-accessibility-named-controls-298766c454bc), by Rob Whitaker, might be the answer. 

What do you think?

Comment: A good article thanks for sending over, definitely simplifies the process a bit going forward and believe this will probably be the future for accessibility as it is a bit clunky to implement and displayed for users